# iOS 11.4 component not in list for Xcode 9.4

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm using Xcode 9.4 on MacOS 10.13.5

I want to test on iOS 11.4 in the iOS emulator

But the option to install the 11.4 image is not showing

I open Xcode and click Xcode > Preferences > Components

And iOS 11.4 is not in the list

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in simulator for Xcode 9.4 is for iOS 11.4. That's why it's not in the list. There's no need to install any extra simulator.

Comment: Hmm, in my infinite wisdom I must have deleted the files back when I thought I didn't need them. Hence why the iOS version won't appear in drop down menus when I try to add a virtual device. You wouldn't happen to know how I would reinstall these files? I'm gathering I could by uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode, but maybe there's another way ...